# multiple ggplot linear regression lines

Tags: r, ggplot2, regression

I am plotting the occurrence of a species according to numerous variables on the same plot. There are many other variables but I've only kept the important ones for the sake of this post:

```
 > str(GH) 
 'data.frame':  288 obs. of  21 variables: 
 $ Ee       : int  2 2 1 7 6 3 0 9 3 7 ... 
 $ height   : num  14 25.5 25 21.5 18.5 36 18 31.5 28.5 19 ... 
 $ legumes  : num  0 0 55 30 0 0 55 10 30 0 ... 
 $ grass    : num  60 50 30 35 40 35 40 40 35 30 ... 
 $ forbs    : num  40 70 40 50 65 70 40 65 70 70 ...
```

I've managed to plot this fine and get it looking nice using (where Ee is the species in question):

```
ggplot(data=GH,aes(y=y,x=x),ylab="Number of individuals (N)",xlab="Percentage cover (%); OR  Height(cm))+
geom_jitter(aes(legumes,Ee),colour="blue")+ 
geom_jitter(aes(grass,Ee),colour="green")+ 
geom_jitter(aes(forbs,Ee),colour="red")+ 
geom_jitter(aes(height,Ee),colour="black")
```

However, I want to add regression lines for each of the variables (and calculate the R squared value), and have had no luck so far. Also the axes labels refuse to change from X and Y which I have never encountered before. Could anybody give me any help on this? Cheers

Comment: You seem to be trying to label `ggplot` like base graphics. This won't work. Try `+ labs(x = "Percentage cover (%)", y = "Number of individuals (N)")`

Answer (score 15):

Using `geom_smooth` geom in ggplot2 gets regression lines to display. I am using `mtcars` data set as it's very similar to yours:

```
ggplot(mtcars) + 
  geom_jitter(aes(disp,mpg), colour="blue") + geom_smooth(aes(disp,mpg), method=lm, se=FALSE) +
  geom_jitter(aes(hp,mpg), colour="green") + geom_smooth(aes(hp,mpg), method=lm, se=FALSE) +
  geom_jitter(aes(qsec,mpg), colour="red") + geom_smooth(aes(qsec,mpg), method=lm, se=FALSE) +
  labs(x = "Percentage cover (%)", y = "Number of individuals (N)")
```

Also, I removed `aes(y=y,x=x)` from `ggplot` as it carries no meaning. The result:

[image]

There is more elaborate (but better looking) method to accomplish the same using `melt` from `reshape2` package:

```
require(ggplot2)
require(reshape2)
mtcars2 = melt(mtcars, id.vars='mpg')
ggplot(mtcars2) +
  geom_jitter(aes(value,mpg, colour=variable),) + geom_smooth(aes(value,mpg, colour=variable), method=lm, se=FALSE) +
  facet_wrap(~variable, scales="free_x") +
  labs(x = "Percentage cover (%)", y = "Number of individuals (N)")
```

One important element of this solution is option `scales="free_x"` that allows independent scale of X across each facet plot.

[image]

Comment: Perfect! That's exactly what I wanted to do! Thanks. First time playing around with ggplot. Do you know how I could add the R sq. values to each of the lines? I have the values by using: Eeleg<-lm(Ee~legumes) etc but I would like to place them on the graph

Comment: Is it possible to include the correlation coefficients, slopes, and intercepts with this approach?

Comment: I have tried the following code to add the equations and the R², but it didn't work:


```
stat_poly_eq(aes(label = paste(..eq.label.., ..rr.label.., sep = "~~~~")),
label.x.npc = "right", label.y.npc = "bottom",
formula = y~x, parse = TRUE, size = 2.8)
```