# ggplot with multiple regression lines to show random effects

Tags: r, plot, ggplot2, linear-regression

I am aware of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12281663/4089351) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25753089/4089351) posts. However, I don't seem to get the expected result when I try the following:

The data can be loaded directly from [here](https://github.com/RInterested/SIMULATIONS_and_PROOFS/blob/master/athletes%20mixed%20effects). The idea is that in a completely made-up data set, the levels of glucose in blood for several athletes at the completion of different races would depend on some fictitious amino acid (AAA):

[image]

The call for the plot was:

```
ggplot(df, aes(x = AAA, y = glucose, color=athletes)) +  
  geom_point() + geom_smooth(method="lm", fill=NA)
```

And I expected to get different lines for each one of the athletes, instead of one single regression line. My idea was to get something similar to [this](https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/188061/67822).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

something like this?

```
ggplot(df, aes(x = AAA, y = glucose, color=athletes, group=athletes)) +  
  geom_point() + geom_smooth(method="lm", fill=NA)
```

[image]

or maybe you would prefer this

```
ggplot(df, aes(x = AAA, y = glucose, color=as.factor(athletes), group=as.factor(athletes))) +  
  geom_point() + geom_smooth(method="lm", fill=NA)
```

[image]

Comment: Exactly! Let me do something to help change this reputation number you have right now ("666")... :-) I'll accept your answer as soon as the system allows - 8 min.

Comment: BTW. Do you happen to know why it's giving me these confusion blue hues, as opposed to very different colors for each athlete?

Comment: Thank you. Most definitely. I didn't realize until now that you have to wait 8 min before accepting. If I forget to do so, please remind me.